# getLocationOnScreen() returns zero

Tags: android

am using the following code for getting the position of a button but it always returning zero.
Why this happening

```
    Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final int[] x=new int[2];
    b.getLocationOnScreen(x);
```

Iam sure someone here can help me

Comment: where you are calling above code? in onCreate()?

Comment: It depends whether you are calling this function after creation of your layout or before creation of you layout on activity.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525945/getlocationonscreen-of-a-child-of-gridlayout/19526211#19526211). Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this..

```
Button b;
```

in Globel variable

then `onCreate()`

```
b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

After `onCreate();`

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
       final int[] x=new int[2];
        b.getLocationOnScreen(x);
}
```